# What is Islamic view of evil eye?

Tags: evil-eye

Does the concept of evil eye (nazar) have a place in Islam? If so, what does Islam think about it? How can one get protected from it? Could [Blue eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBlue_eyes.JPG) protect one from evil eye according to Islam?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The concept of the evil eye is established as such from [various ahadith](http://sunnah.com/search/evil-eye) of the Prophet Muhammad (saws) - for example [this one](http://sunnah.com/urn/53840):

> The Prophet said, "The effect of an evil eye is a fact."

Scholars interpret the ayah on hasad in Surat al-Falaq to be referring to the evil eye as well:

> And from the evil of an envier when he envies." [al-Falaq:5](http://quran.com/113/5)

In another [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/673650), the Prophet (saws) said:

> "If there was anything that could overcome the Decree then the (evil) eye would overcome it, and when you are requested to wash (due to it) then wash."

The evil eye refers to when a person "harms" another with his eye. It starts when the person likes a thing and becomes jealous of it, then evil feelings affect his disposition and view of that thing by means of his repeated looking at the object of his jealousy.

The Muslim believes that nothing happens without the permission and knowledge of Allah SWT, and this is something that Allah created. We ask Allah to be protected by various means (all found in the sunnah):

1. By having faith in Allah and His Power and knowing that we only seek help and refuge in Him
2. By reciting the last two surahs for protection (the mu'awwidhaat)
3. By means of this supplication:

   > A’udhu bi kalimat-illah il-taammati min sharri ma khalaqa
   >
   > I seek refuge in the perfect words of Allaah from the evil of that which He has created.
4. Other supplications to be found in the sunnah

Finally, since this is a matter of the *ghaib* or the unseen, anything we know about it must come from a source that we trust to have knowledge of the unseen, i.e. only from Allah or His Messenger. So if someone claims that blue eyes, in addition to the methods of ruqyah provided above, protect from the evil eye, then they need to bring forth a proof for why that is.

Comment: Excellent answer, but you should add something about the stance on talismans such as the blue eyes mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Another reference: "And indeed, those who disbelieve would almost make you slip with their eyes when they hear the message, and they say, "Indeed, he is mad."" (68:51)

Comment: like @SystemDown mentioned, great answer and would like more on Blue Eye. The correct way to protect is as mentioned by 'Al Ummat' : recite two last surahs, Al Falaq and Al Nass, Surat 113 and 114

Comment: Hmm @Nasir I mentioned the last two surahs already in my answer, and I addressed the blue eyes at the end of my answer. I don't know anything else about the blue eyes, so if you have something to add, go right ahead

Comment: I know this post is a little old however I was wondering if one believes they are afflicted by the evil eye should one perform gusul prior to practising the above 4 instructions or is gusul not a pre-requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Asalamu wa alikum,

> > Ibn 'Abbas reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying: The influence of an evil eye is a fact; if anything would
> >     precede the destiny it would be the influence of an evil eye, and when
> >     you are asked to take bath (as a cure) from the influence of an evil
> >     eye, you should take bath.
>
> وَحَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ الدَّارِمِيُّ،
>   وَحَجَّاجُ بْنُ الشَّاعِرِ، وَأَحْمَدُ بْنُ خِرَاشٍ، قَالَ عَبْدُ
>   اللَّهِ أَخْبَرَنَا وَقَالَ الآخَرَانِ، حَدَّثَنَا مُسْلِمُ بْنُ
>   إِبْرَاهِيمَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا وُهَيْبٌ، عَنِ ابْنِ، طَاوُسٍ عَنْ
>   أَبِيهِ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ
>   ‏ "‏ الْعَيْنُ حَقٌّ وَلَوْ كَانَ شَىْءٌ سَابَقَ الْقَدَرَ سَبَقَتْهُ
>   الْعَيْنُ وَإِذَا اسْتُغْسِلْتُمْ فَاغْسِلُوا ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> > Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Apostle said, "The evil eye is a fact," and he forbade
>   tattooing.
>
> حَدَّثَنِي يَحْيَى، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ، عَنْ مَعْمَرٍ، عَنْ
>   هَمَّامٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ الْعَيْنُ حَقٌّ ‏"‏‏.‏ وَنَهَى عَنِ
>   الْوَشْمِ‏.‏

These hadiths tell you that there is the evil eye in Islam.

> > Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) used to seek
> >     protection against the evil of jinn and the evil eyes till Surat
> >     Al-Falaq and Surat An-Nas were revealed. After they were revealed, he
> >     took to them for seeking Allah's protection and left everything
> >     besides them.
>
> [At- Tirmidhi].
>
> وعن أبي سعيد الخدري رضي الله عنه قال ‏:‏ كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم يتعوذ من الجان، وعين الإنسان، حتى نزلت المعوذتان، فلما نزلتا، أخذ
>   بهما وترك ما سواهما ‏.‏ (‏‏(‏رواه الترمذي وقال ‏:‏حديث حسن ‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏

This is how you protect your self, recite the two last surahs, Al Falaq and Al Nass, Surat 113 and 114