# Does the evil eye only affect muslims?

Tags: evil-eye

I've been taught and I have also read that the evil eye is real.  What I don't understand is that there are many many extremely rich and wealthy non Muslims, who many many people will envy.  Why don't they ever get affected by the evil eye?

Or does the evil eye only affect you if you're Muslim?

Comment: [very related](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/280/what-is-islamic-view-of-evil-eye)

Comment: Negative thoughts of others don't affect if one himself doesn't allow (--how not to, that's another thing.) Equally on muslims and non-muslims.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The evil eye is present in many cultures and in at least several religions in addition to Islam.

- Consider the book:
  ["The Evil Eye in the Bible and in Rabbinic Literature" by Rivka Ulmer](http://books.google.com/books?id=cwB8Hfkjpx0C&pg=PA176&dq=egypt%20%22evil%20eye%22&cd=1&hl=en#v=onepage&q=egypt%20%22evil%20eye%22&f=false), which cites multiple references to the evil eye in in the Jewish cannon.
- In Hinduism the [Nazar Battu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazar_Battu) is worn to ward off the evil eye.
- In north east Africa there is a widespread belief in the evil eye called "[Buda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buda_%28folk_religion%29)". The orthodox Christians living there believe it to be a form of demonic possession or oppression.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer if the evil eye can affect non-Muslims.

Answer (score 1):

As muslim we believe that the evil eye exists in this world according to the hadith of the prophet Muhammed (PBUH)

In sahih Muslim,

> Abu Huraira reported so many ahadeeth from Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) and he reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying: The influence of an evil eye is a fact.

another hadith in sahih Muslim

> Ibn 'Abbas reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying: The influence of an evil eye is a fact; if anything would precede the destiny it would be the influence of an evil eye, and when you are asked to take bath (as a cure) from the influence of an evil eye, you should take bath.

and in Bukhary,

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   The Prophet said, "The effect of an evil eye is a fact." And he prohibited tattooing.

So in Islam we know it exists and it may affect muslims and non-Muslims too. So we should seek refuge by reading the Day and night athkar, or reading the 3 last surahs of the Quran(An-Nas,Al-Falaq and As-samad) after each prayer.

> Narrated Uqbah ibn Amir:
>   The Messenger of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) commanded me to recite Mu'awwidhatan (the last two surahs of the Qur'an) after every prayer.

[Nasai(Hasan](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13#158))

Answer (score 0):

This world is heaven for non believers .
Allah swt only tests his believing servants , he afflicts muslims with such things as evil eye , magic , etc so that he could erase all sins of his believing servants and would raise their status . If we don't see white people getting affected by evil eye m magic . It's because this world is heaven for them, they're in ease . 
While for muslims , this world is only a small journey , afflictions and trials are parts of their  life . All prophets were gone through afflictions , all muslims in this world are in difficulty . It's because this world is not a heaven for us . Our heaven is where Allah swt has destined .

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. O learn more about this site and our model I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help].