# The correct procedure for dealing with the evil eye

Tags: curse, evil-eye, protection

I have read this with regards to the evil eye [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/280/what-is-islamic-view-of-evil-eye) however it seems to explain how to protect yourself from the evil eye. However how does one cure the evil eye once one believes he or she has been affected by it? 
Is it the same procedure? Secondly from what I vaguely understand a bath is required, can this be any bath or is ghusl with specific intention of purifying ones self from the evil eye required? Does one have to go into the bath with intention of purification or can one take a regular bath and then practise those instructions in the above link (if they are for curing)?

Answer (score -1):

The process of aieen or evil eye remidy explained in hadith is to ask the envier to make Ghusal or Wudu and use that water he used to make wadu or ghusal and pour it on the back of the effected person which will fix the issue for both.

But in relaity you cant ask anyone to do that now a days - people will turn mad and say that you are accusing them and heads will role

So instead use the method of reciting Quran to fend off evil eye and there are two more prayers defined in Saheeh Muslim for this but best is to recite quranic verses as explained in the link you posted.

Allah knows best.

Comment: I understand using the water of wudu cannot be used these days however is one required to take a bath and Is this bath gusul or just a regular one? Like must intention be made prior to taking a bath as is with gusul and wudu?

Comment: i though it was already implied every-time you take a bath you should make ghusul, since you are under water already having a bath not making ghusul would be waist of water in my opinion.